# Tkinter for Pandas (excel)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, tkinter

I am very new in tkinter can you guys help me. I want to enter the main program to process excel file data into the gui program.

I have all my code in my github so if u down to help me, u can check it here : https://github.com/HFZjoe/Tkinter-for-Excel

Comment: does that mean, you want to use excel as a small data base?

Comment: i want to turn my excel file (3 files ) into dataframe after i browse the file. so my main program can calculate the dataframe. At the end the output will be in excel file again